# Failure deducing non-type template argument because of char-array to pointer decay?

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction, non-type-template-parameter

Given the following code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <source_location>

template<std::size_t N>
struct StringWrapper {
    // consteval to force only compile-time strings
    consteval StringWrapper(const char (&format_string)[N], std::source_location source_location = std::source_location::current())
        : SourceInfo{ source_location } {
        std::copy(std::begin(format_string), std::end(format_string), std::begin(FormatString));
    }

    char FormatString[N]{};

    // This here to motivate not using StringWrapper as non-type template argument
    std::source_location SourceInfo{};
};

// class-template-argument-deduction is not necessary here, see the first case in main

// variadic template, thus putting std::source_location at the end is not an option
template<std::size_t N, class... Args>
void log(StringWrapper<N> format_string, Args&&... args);

int main()
{
    log(StringWrapper{ "This {}, explicitly instantiating, but deducing the parameter" }, "works");
    log("This {}, could not match 'StringWrapper<N>' against 'const char *'", "fails");
}
```

What could be a possible workaround to this issue that would not require a change on the callsite?

One possibility is to use a `std::string_view`, however that would not give me access to `N` as a constant expression in the implementation of `log` and is thus not an option in my case.

Another possibility is to directly take a `const char (&)[N]`, however then I am losing the `std::source_location` which is not an option either.

I understand why overload resolution would favor a function that takes a `const char*` over a function that takes a `const char (&)[N]`, however I do not understand why 'StringWrapper' is not even attempted to match against 'const char (&)[N]' however.

Comment: "_why 'StringWrapper' is not even attempted to match against 'const char (&)[N]' however._": Template argument deduction always requires identical match of types (excepting qualifiers, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and inheritance relation in certain circumstances).

Comment: I would suggest using a user-defined string literal to make it look a bit nicer than `StringWrapper{/*...*/}`.

Comment: it's not like the location would be correct anyway.

Comment: @user17732522 A user-defined string literal is the last option I could see indeed, I would still much prefer to avoid that as it is, in my case, a breaking API change.

Comment: @appleapple that's correct, while refactoring I moved the call to `std::source_location::current()` and forgot to move it back, I will edit the post to correct that.

Comment: @HannoBänsch: "*as it is, in my case, a breaking API change.*" Then leave the old overload in place.

Comment: @user17732522 I don't quite follow the deduction rules you lay out here. What I am passing is a `const char (&)[M]` and trying to deduce the `N` in a `StringWrapper<N>`. This would work if deduction were similar to using implicit conversions to the class template. But do I understand it correctly that this is simply not how the deduction works in this case? It would be curious to explore if something like this would be possible to add to the standard.

Comment: @HannoBänsch Template argument deduction (with minor exceptions I listed) requires that the argument's type can be matched against the parameter type directly. No implicit conversions are considered. Adding something like this is not going to be feasible. First because it would likely break old code relying on the specific behavior of overload resolution and more importantly because it is impossible in general. It is generally impossible to verify whether there is a unique `N` such that the implicit conversion is allowed. You would have to test every possible value for that.

Comment: @user17732522 While I despise the argument of backwards compatibility I get it. Though surely there is a conceivable possibility where this "CTAD-implicit-conversion-overload-resolution" has the lowest priority during overload resolution, in which case it would not break any old code. I'm obviously not a standard writer, so I don't know how feasible it is for such a restriction to be slotted into the standard, but just conceptually it seems possible. As for finding the unique `N`, surely the same argument and logic applies here as it does for CTAD, meaning it is possible.

Comment: @HannoBänsch Unfortunately giving new rules with lower priority are not sufficient since overload resolution _failing_ is a valid outcome that a program can rely on via SFINAE. Pretty much any change to overload resolution rules can break code and so the impact must be considered. As for CTAD as in the posted answer, that doesn't need to figure out `N`, because the deduction guide explicitly tells the compiler that `N` is supposed to be the size of the array. That's the whole reason this indirect approach works.

Comment: You could ask for adding a deduction-guide-like feature for function templates. I think that sounds much more feasible as it would be opt-in and therefore not breaking old code, but I haven't thought about it in detail. There would only be very few use cases in which the same can't be achieved by another function template overload instead and the trick from the answer via CTAD is almost always a valid replacement. So I don't know what the committee would make of such a proposal.

Comment: A deduction-guide for functions sounds interesting, if I ever feel like I don't have enough problems in my life I will consider whether I wanna think about it in more detail. Thanks for all the input, it's very interesting to me  

Answer (score 2):

you can use class template argument deduction to do this (change `log` to object constructor instead of normal function)

```cpp
template<std::size_t N, class... Args>
struct log{
    log(StringWrapper<N> src, Args&&... args){}
};

template<std::size_t N, class... Args>
log(const char(&)[N],Args&&...) -> log<N,Args...>;

template<std::size_t N, class... Args>
log(StringWrapper<N>,Args&&...) -> log<N,Args...>;
```

Comment: While technically working it too has a downside in that `log` no longer is a regular function, even considering the constructor call itself. It might not be immediately relevant right now but it's a notable difference. Nonetheless it might very well be a good solution for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Although you said you somehow need `N` inside `log` as constant expression, just in case someone reach here don't need it.

Change `StringWrapper` to non-template can also solve the problem.

```
struct StringWrapper {
    template<std::size_t N>
    consteval StringWrapper(const char(&format_string)[N], std::source_location source_location = std::source_location::current())
        : FormatString{format_string}, SourceInfo{ source_location }{}

    std::string_view FormatString;
    std::source_location SourceInfo{};
};

template<typename ... Args>
void log(StringWrapper src, Args&&...){
   auto N = src.FormatString.size(); // N, but not constant expression
}
```